# Kubernetes Ingress not adding the application URL for grafana dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I have install the Grafan in my Kubenernetes 1.9 cluster. When I access with my ingress URL  (http://sample.com/grafana/ ) getting the first page. After that javascript, css download not adding /grafana to the URL.

here is my ingress rule:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingress-v1
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sample.com
    secretName: ngerss-tls
  rules:
  - host: sample.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /grafana/
        backend:
          serviceName: grafana-grafana
          servicePort: 80
```

Here I see the discussion about the same topic. but its not helping my issue.

https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/issues/860
Below images shows first request goes to /grafana/ but second request didn't get added `/grafana/` in the url.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your ingress rule is correct and nginx creates correct virtual host to forward traffic to grafana's service (I left only needed strings to show):

```
 server {
    server_name sample.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

    location ~* ^/grafana/(?<baseuri>.*) {

        set $proxy_upstream_name "default-grafana-grafana-80";

        set $namespace      "default";
        set $ingress_name   "grafana-ingress-v1";


    rewrite /grafana/(.*) /$1 break;
    rewrite /grafana/ / break;
    proxy_pass http://default-grafana-grafana-80;

    }
```

And yes, when you go to `sample.com/grafana/` you get the response from grafana pod, but it redirects to `sample.com/login` page (you see this from screenshot you provided):

```
$ curl -v -L http://sample.com/grafana/
*   Trying 192.168.99.100...
* Connected to sample.com (192.168.99.100) port 80 (#0)
> GET /grafana/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: sample.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: nginx/1.13.5
< Date: Tue, 30 Jan 2018 21:55:21 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 29
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: /login
< Set-Cookie: grafana_sess=c07ab2399d82fef4; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: redirect_to=%252F; Path=/
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host sample.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://sample.com/login'
* Found bundle for host sample.com: 0x563ff9bf7f20 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host sample.com
* Connected to sample.com (192.168.99.100) port 80 (#0)
> GET /login HTTP/1.1
> Host: sample.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.13.5
< Date: Tue, 30 Jan 2018 21:55:21 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 21
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host sample.com left intact
default backend 404
```

because by default grafana's `root_url` is just `/`:

```
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/
```

and when request redirects to just `sample.com` nginx forwards it to default backend 404.

**Solution:**

You need to change `root_url` grafana's server setting to `/grafana/`:

```
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/
```

You can do this changing this setting in grafana's `configmap` object.

Comment: @nickoly Thanks for the answer. I will test this.

Comment: to support all domains use -->  root_url = %(protocol)s://0.0.0.0:%(http_port)s/grafana/

Answer (score 0):

In order to serve Grafana with a prefix /grafana (e.g., http://k8s.example.com/grafana), add the following to your **helm values.yaml** .

```yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

  path: /grafana/?(.*)
  hosts:
    - k8s.example.com

grafana.ini:
  server:
    root_url: http://localhost:3000/grafana # this host can be localhost
```

And upgrade helm grafana release as follows:

```sh
helm -n namespace_name upgrade -f values.yaml relase_name stable/grafana
```